# Problema al renderizar vista en php bajo el patrón MVC

Tags: php, mvc, xampp, aplicación-web

¡Hola!,esperando y me puedan orientar, estoy realizando una aplicación web con PHP utilizando la arquitectura MVC en el, tengo una vista en la cual muestro información de un usuario, pero al dar clic al botón siguiente usuario, se activa una función onclick la cual envía al controlador el ID del siguiente usuario mediante una petición Ajax y en esta misma refresco la pagina para que me muestre los nuevos resultados que se hicieron con el ID que se paso al controlador, el problema es que en la pagina no se reflejan los cambios pero al inspeccionar la pagina en la pestaña de Network si me muestra la pagina renderizada correctamente con los nuevos datos de las consultas al modelo que se hicieron con el ID que envié.

Agrego función onclick

```php
function siguienteUsuario(id_usuario){
        //recibiendo el valor de ID de la session del productor
        var_id_usuario_sig= id_usuario;
        //incrementamos +1 para consultar el siguiente usuario
        var_id_usuario_sig ++ ;
        alert("Pasamos el ID siguiente :"+var_id_usuario_sig);
        //enviando al controlador el id mediante AJAX 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {var_id_usuario_sig: var_id_usuario_sig},
            //enviamos al controlador llamado"areaFacilitador
            //al metodo "sigUsuario" del controlador
            url:  "<?php echo constant('URL')?>areaFacilitador/sigUsuario",
            success:function(r){
                if(r){
                    alert("id enviado");
                    //Se envio correctmente el ID all controlador, refrescamos la
                    //pagina para renderizar con los datos nuevos
                    location.reload();
                }else{
                    alert("id no enviada");
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Agrego función del controlador donde recibo el ID del siguiente usuario

```php
public function sigUsuario(){
            $id_sig= $_POST['var_id_usuario_sig'];
            echo "EL NUEVO ID ES : ". $id_sig;
            //Solicitamos la informacion del usuario al modelo con la funcion llamada "getAreaTrabajo"
            $areaTrabajoDATA=$this->model->getAreaTrabajo(['id_proyecto' => $variable_id_proyecto, 'id_usuario' =>$id_sig]);
            var_dump($areaTrabajoDATA);
            
             $datos=[
                   'listado'=> $areaTrabajoDATA
            ];
                //volvemos a renderizar la misma vista con los datos nuevos
                $this->view->render('areaFacilitador/index',$datos);
}
```

Es mi primer aplicación que realizo utilizando la arquitectura MVC tal vez estoy aplicando mal algún elemento,ya he tratado de cargar los datos nuevos de diferentes formas pero no logro tener dicha información del nuevo usuario, ojala y me puedan orientar.
Éxito en sus actividades, ¡Gracias!.

Comment: Hola Víctor, por favor pulsa en [edit]  y cambia las imágenes por el texto del código, pues es más fácil de analizarlo y de reproducir en problema si fuera necesario. Convendría también que hagas depuraciones de los datos para ver si existen, qué estructura tienen, etc. Cuando un código falla hay que depurarlo lo más que puedas.

Comment: OK gracias, ya realice los cambios recomendados, seguire checando el código mediante depuración. Saludos y Grax.